# Preventing overlapping shapes while dragging on a Pane

Tags: javafx

I've looked at similar questions but they all are concerned with collision detection rather than preventing overlap. I've gotten most of it to work with the below code:

```
private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onPress = mouseEvent -> {
    xDrag = this.getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
    yDrag = this.getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
};

private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDrag = mouseEvent -> {
    for (Shape shape : getAllShapes()) {
        if (!this.equals(shape)) {
            Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(shape, this);
            if (intersect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    this.setCenterX(mouseEvent.getX() + xDrag);
    this.setCenterY(mouseEvent.getY() + yDrag);
};
```

However, the problem is, once there is a tiniest bit of overlap, the Shape is no longer draggable at all. Meaning, if I drag a shape to another, once they become essentially tangent, neither of them are draggable anymore. What I want to happen is just that, for example, if you try to drag a circle onto another, the circle won't follow the mouse position as long as the future position of the drag will cause an overlap.

I can't figure out exactly how to accomplish this.

EDIT: Minimum Reproducible Example:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    static Circle circle1 = new DraggableCircle(100, 200);
    static Circle circle2 = new DraggableCircle(200, 300);
    static Circle[] circleList = new Circle[]{circle1, circle2};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

DraggableCircle.java

```
public class DraggableCircle extends Circle {
    private double xDrag, yDrag;

    public DraggableCircle(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y, 30);
        this.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        this.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        this.setStrokeWidth(1.5);
        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onPress);
        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onDrag);
    }

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onPress = (mouseEvent) -> {
        xDrag = this.getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
        yDrag = this.getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
    };

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDrag = mouseEvent -> {
        for (Shape shape : Main.circleList) {
            if (!this.equals(shape)) {
                Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(shape, this);
                if (intersect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        this.setCenterX(mouseEvent.getX() + xDrag);
        this.setCenterY(mouseEvent.getY() + yDrag);
    };
}
```

This also has an issue where dragging too quickly causes a noticeable overlap between the circles, before the drag detection ends.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but dragging too quickly makes the distance between the nodes vary. Not sure if this is fixable. And if possible, I would want the dragged shape to glide along the other's border when trying to drag onto it, sort of such that the dragged shape is as close to the mouse as possible without overlapping other shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A simple (imperfect) solution**

The following algorithm will allow a node to continue to be dragged after an intersection has occurred:

1. Record the current draggable shape position.
2. Set the new position.
3. Check the intersection.
4. If an intersection is detected, reset the position to the original position.

An implementation replaces the drag handler in the supplied minimal example code from the question.

```
private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDrag = (mouseEvent) -> {
    double priorCenterX = getCenterX();
    double priorCenterY = getCenterY();

    this.setCenterX(mouseEvent.getX() + xDrag);
    this.setCenterY(mouseEvent.getY() + yDrag);

    for (Shape shape : Main.circleList) {
        if (!this.equals(shape)) {
            Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(shape, this);
            if (intersect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
                this.setCenterX(priorCenterX);
                this.setCenterY(priorCenterY);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This handler does work better than what you had, it does at least allow you to continue dragging after the intersection.

But, yes, if you drag quickly it will leave a visible space between nodes when it has detected that the drag operation would cause an intersection, which isn't ideal.

Also, the additional requirement you added in your comment about having the dragged shape glide along a border would require a more sophisticated solution.

**Other potential solutions**

I don't offer code for these more sophisticated solutions here.

One potential brute force solution is to interpolate the prior center with the new center and then, in a loop, slowly move the dragged object along the interpolated line until an intersection is detected, then just back it out to the last interpolated value to prevent the intersection.  You can do this by calculating and applying a normalized (1 unit distance) movement vector.  That might fix space between intersected nodes.

Similarly to get the gliding, on the intersection, you could just update either the interpolated x or y value rather than both.

There may be more sophisticated methods with geometry math applied, especially if you know shape geometry along with movement vectors and surface normals.

Comment: I was thinking of a sort of gliding solutions with something similar that you mentioned, but your solution is ideal for now while I focus on other parts of my program. Much appreciated! Especially because my gliding solution with that math seemed a bit convoluted and I thought there would be an easier way, but it seems I'll have to go that path.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for @jewelsea answer.
On top of @jewelsea answer, I would like to provide a fix for the "space between nodes" issue.

So you might have already observed that when you drag fast, it will not cover each and every pixel in the drag path. It varies with the speed of the drag. So when you decide to move it to the previous recorded point, we will do a quick math, to see if there is any gap between the two nodes, if yes:

We will do a math "to determine a point along a line which is at distance d" and move the drag circle to that point. Here..

- start point of line is : previous recorded point
- end point of line is : the intersected shape center
- d is : the gap between the two shapes.

So the updated code to the @jewelsea answer is as below:

```
private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDrag = (mouseEvent) -> {
    double priorCenterX = getCenterX();
    double priorCenterY = getCenterY();

    this.setCenterX(mouseEvent.getX() + xDrag);
    this.setCenterY(mouseEvent.getY() + yDrag);

    for (Circle shape : Main.circleList) {
        if (!this.equals(shape)) {
            Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(shape, this);
            if (intersect.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
                Point2D cx = new Point2D(priorCenterX, priorCenterY);
                Point2D px = new Point2D(shape.getCenterX(), shape.getCenterY());
                double d = cx.distance(px);
                if (d > getRadius() + shape.getRadius()) {
                    cx = pointAtDistance(cx, px, d - getRadius() - shape.getRadius());
                }
                this.setCenterX(cx.getX());
                this.setCenterY(cx.getY());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};

private Point2D pointAtDistance(Point2D p1, Point2D p2, double distance) {
    double lineLength = p1.distance(p2);
    double t = distance / lineLength;
    double dx = ((1 - t) * p1.getX()) + (t * p2.getX());
    double dy = ((1 - t) * p1.getY()) + (t * p2.getY());
    return new Point2D(dx, dy);
}
```

Comment: Clean solution! Much appreciated!

Comment: I do want to want to mention though that there's an error with your solution, now that I've tried to implement it in my own code. With more than two nodes, if two are tangent, a third can overlap one of them, and with more tangent nodes, the overlap is more sizeable. But regardless it works in the code sample I gave and I would probably just defer this problem later and use some math to implement a gliding solution if possible. Just thought I'd mention this.